# Read double numbers of a CSV to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with double numbers like below:

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
```

but when i read it to a DataFrame it converts :

`0  34.623660   78.024693   0 
1   30.286711   43.894998   0`

and the dtype is: `dtype: float64`

I tried to change the `float_precision` to  `float_precision="high"` but that not worked too!

So how to read the exact number to the DataFrame ?

Comment: If it's a `float64`, it has enough precision for the value you're reading in. How are you showing that data? It's likely that however you're printing it out is what's causing it to reduce precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just appears to be rounded but it isn't. If you access the individual cell you can get the exact value you passed. i.e

`df[0][0]` returns `34.623659624516968`

Comment: yes, i use `df.head()' and it is not show all the numbers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the value of `Decimal` modules `getcontext().prec`. This will increase the number of decimal places.

Comment: it is not the case because: `Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow]`